# Como hago un botón que descargue un archivo?

Tags: css, html5

Esto es lo que hice pero no funciona y no entiendo que es lo que esta mal, solo me abre en la página la imagen pero no me da la opción de descargarlo, no aparece ni error ni nada solo la abre en la pagina.

```css
.button{
    background: #F77F00;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px;
    color: var(--blanco);
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: #eb7900;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.constructionequipment.com/sites/ce/files/styles/content/public/International-MV-truck.jpg?itok=xllmxO7e" class="button" download>Descargar imagen</a>
```

Comment: debes poner el enlace que se va a descargar por ejemplo esta imagen https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-pizarra-matematicas-realista_23-2148163817.jpg

Comment: "No me da la opción ..." ¿Qué pasa entonces? ¿No pasa nada? ¿Aparece algún mensaje de error? ¿Despliega alguna otra cosa?

Comment: Ya intentaste guardando el archivo en tu pc?

Comment: @CandidMoe nada más me aparece el archivo en otra página como si omitiera el atributo de download

Comment: @JuanFelipeRubiano Ya esta guardado el archivo en mi pc pero de todos modos no funciona

Comment: ¿Qué navegador utilizas?